# Pandas- issue with numpy.where method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

this line is a part of my method that sums all dataframe cells where:

1. the "location" col equals cntry (user input)
2. the "date" col equals temp (changes in a for loop (user input)

   ```
            sum_of_cases = sum_of_cases + np.where((self.covid_data['location'] == str(cntry)) & (self.covid_data['date'] == temp), self.covid_data['new_cases'], 0).sum()
   ```

the value of sum_of_cases doesn't change, it equals 0.
the data frame contains numbers so I can't understand where's the problem

Comment: Place 5 rows of your dataframe. Paste the part of the code with the variables involved in this expression. So that it can be reproduced and somehow help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never actually need `np.where`, especially if you're working with dataframes. I'm not sure if this is what you need but maybe it's close.

```
mask = (self.covid_data['location'] == str(cntry)) & (self.covid_data['date'] == temp)

self.covid_data.loc[mask, 'new_cases'].sum()
```